# Calculate Uncertainty of Percentage in R and plot in scatter plot

Tags: r, plot, percentage, scatter-plot, uncertainty

I have this data set where I calculate the percentage of fall given an age. Total Members is the whole date by a given age, and members fallen is the amount of falls within the total member.

```
age status membersFallen totalMember percentage
37      1      208       14824        1.4
38      1      443       14736        3.0
39      1      610       13190        4.6
40      1      563       12209        4.6
41      1      539       11186        4.8
42      1      528       11141        4.7
43      1      546       10118        5.4
44      1      527        9677        5.4
45      1      560        9399        6.0
```

This data generates a crescent graph, and what I'm willing to do is to calculate the uncertainty of this percentages and plot an error bar in scatter plot.

Thanks

Comment: What plotting code did you use so far? You can look at `prop.test` for one way to generate confidence intervals for proportions. You should be explicit about what modeling assumption you want to use to generate confidence intervals.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You may get an answer faster if you share with us what you already tried with a [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?s=1|7.0421) example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you thinking of the confidence interval for binomial proportion?
see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval
E.g. `binom.test(208,14824)` the 95% CI is [1.22, 1.61] for your sample estimate 1.40 (percentage)

Comment: Thank you! It helped me a lot. My Solution in R was use **prop.test(k, n)**  (http://www.r-tutor.com/elementary-statistics/interval-estimation/interval-estimate-population-proportion) command to calculate the ci.